# Swift CoreData to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

here is my code:
    import UIKit
import CoreData

```
class WeekController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}





var dayPlan: [DayPlan] = {

    var mondayDayPlan = DayPlan()
    var mondayDayPlanWorkout : Workout?
    mondayDayPlan.dayNameLabel = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayNameCD
    mondayDayPlan.codeNameLabel = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayCodeNameCD
    mondayDayPlan.task01 = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayTask01
    mondayDayPlan.task02 = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayTask02
    mondayDayPlan.task03 = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayTask03
    mondayDayPlan.task04 = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayTask04
    mondayDayPlan.task05 = mondayDayPlanWorkout?.mondayTask05
    mondayDayPlan.dayIconImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "biceps")



    var tuesdayDayPlan = DayPlan()
    tuesdayDayPlan.dayNameLabel = "Tuesday"
    tuesdayDayPlan.codeNameLabel = "pojdme na ty nohy"
    tuesdayDayPlan.task01 = "5x1 Legs"
    tuesdayDayPlan.task02 = "5x2 Legs"
    tuesdayDayPlan.task03 = "5x3 Legs"
    tuesdayDayPlan.task04 = "5x4 Legs"
    tuesdayDayPlan.task05 = "5x5 Legs"
    tuesdayDayPlan.dayIconImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ass")
return [mondayDayPlan, tuesdayDayPlan]
```

i have this coreData Model:

```
Entity: **Workout**
with this Attributes:
mondayCodeNameCD
mondayFocusCD
mondayNameCD
mondayTask01
mondayTask02
mondayTask03
mondayTask04
mondayTask05
mondayTask06
more, more, more...
```

tuesdayDayPlan is hardcoded(working good), but mondayDayPlan is with CoreData(shows nothink)...There is no error, but monday is empty, Why? How to get data from CoreData in this case? thanks...

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're doing any sort of fetch or save to your persistent store. I mean you show a function to get the `managedObjectContext`, but you never even use it based on what you're showing. Your persistent store can't magically determine what to save and fetch. Also, for your `mondayDayPlan`, you're declaring it as an optional `Workout` object, but you never initialize it...then you set every property for that `DayPlan` object to something from `mondayDayPlan`, but `mondayDayPlan` is `nil`

Comment: You need to fetch the object from the core data. I see that you are only created a new object using class initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

is sounds as though you are not saving the data correctly to core data.
You can check this easily by opening:
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/

Sort by "Date Modified" to find the app that you just built. find the .sqlite file.
check if the data that is supposed to be there is actually there.

make sure to write "appDelegate.saveContext()" after every time you add an NSManagedObject to your core data.

Good luck!